# Virtual PC - How to convert .nrg file to .vhd

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc, livecd, vhd

I have a live cd of linux. named Knoppix.

I want to run it as a virtual OS on my windows. I have installed windows xp on my PC.
And I am using "Microsoft Virtual PC" for using Virtual OS.

What My aim is "Run Knoppix live cd" as a virtual os on my windows.

Is it possible ? How ?

I have converted that CD in Nero .nrg file. But "Microsoft virtual PC" requires a .vhd file for it. I am confused here.

What should I do to convert .nrg file to .vhd file ?

Or which is the better way ?

Thanks in advance for sharing your knowledge

Sugar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VHD file is a virtual hard drive.  Since Knoppix runs off a cd, you can't convert the CD into a VHD.  However, you can easily run Knoppix on Virtual PC.

Firat you should download a Knoppix ISO from [here](http://www.knoppix.net/get.php), as I don't think Virtual PC can use an NRG file.  Create a new virtual machine in Virtual PC.  During this step, it will ask you if you want to create a new VHD file.  Go ahead and create one, though you will probably not need to use it unless you want to save files onto it between sessions.

Once the virtual machine is created, start it up.  Immediately go to the CD menu and choose "Capture ISO Image".  Select the downloaded Knoppix ISO.  Knoppix should then load up.

Comment: Actually u give a link that is good link their is only .iso file
only pls give me .vhd file format file link pls.


thanx

Comment: Hi @sugar, as I said Knoppix doesn't boot off of hard drives, so there is no .vhd image.  You can create a blank .vhd with Virtual PC, as in my instructions, and then use the downloaded ISO.

Answer (score 0):

I think we have a minor misconception to clear up. While there are image formats that can be of any media (.img), there's some CD specific ones (nrg and iso for example) and hard drive ones such as VHD. You *can* boot VPC off a iso (in lieu of a cd) or a vhd (instead of a hard drive) but in general you cannot convert a iso image to a vhd image.

I'd also note knoppix is a live cd distro so booting it off the iso as dsolimano suggested is valid, and probably the right answer.